# Are these vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, exponentiation

I was trying to think of multiplicative vector spaces, with scalar multiplication replaced by exponentiation and I came up with these as examples

- $C_p$ with $f: \mathbf{Z}_p\times C_p\to C_p$ given by $(n,r)\mapsto r^n$
- $S^1$ with $f:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\to S^1$ given by $(a,z)\mapsto z^a$
- $((F\setminus\{0\})^n, *,1)$ with normal exponentiation over $F$ where $F$ is a field.

I just wanted to check I was right in thinking these are indeed vector spaces?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Have you checked the axioms? (I assume "vector field" at the end should be "vector space")

Comment: Yes, and I think the functions satisfy all of them- but it just doesn't seem like what I'm used to in a vector space

Comment: If you *checked* the axioms, then it's not a matter of "thinking" they do; they either do or do not. If you are unsure about your verification, then ask about that particular step, rather than a completely open ended question that implies you have done nothing beyond stating the definition.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is being asked here. A vector space structure requires two operations, addition and scalar multiplication, but for each structure you've only defined a single operation. Do you also mean to take the vector space addition operation to be the standard group operation on $C_p, S^1, (F \setminus \{0\})^n$, respectively? If so, this should be said explicitly. If you don't have a second operation in mind, by definition you're asking about some algebraic structure other than vector spaces.

Comment: Yes, they do satisfy the axioms I meant to say. I meant the standard group operations yes. I was just wary because these structures aren't what I'm used to with vector fields.

Comment: The first seems to me to be fine. The second is problematic, is this a well-defined operation? I think not. After all, a one-dimensional real vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$,which $S^1$ is not.

Comment: And for the third case, this will certainly fail when eg $F=\mathbb{F}_3$. Your "vector space" has $2^n$ elements and it should have some $3^k$ elements.

Comment: Also, what is $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Travis: View $C_p$ multiplicatively, not additively.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, you're right, of course---that realizes the vector space $\Bbb Z_p$ (over itself), albeit written in an awkward way.

Comment: @Travis: Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a vector space, if $\alpha$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector, then $\alpha\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$ if and only if $\alpha = 0$ or $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

In your second example, the vector addition is supposed to be multiplication of elements of $S^1$, which means the zero vector is the number $1$; but if you take $\alpha=2\neq 0$ and $\mathbf{v}=-1\neq\mathbf{0}$, then you get $\alpha\cdot\mathbf{v} = (-1)^2 = 1 = \mathbf{0}$. Thus, the second example **cannot** be a vector space, and you messed up your verification somewhere. But since you don't tell us what you did, I don't know where you messed up.

The third example is not well-defined; not every field is closed under exponentiation, so you can't just say "standard exponentiation"; for instance, if $F=\mathbb{Q}$, then you cannot calculate $2^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2$; in $\mathbb{R}$ you cannot take $(-1)^{1/2}$; and in $\mathbb{C}$ you run into a problem like the one mentioned above for the second example because exponentiation has a periodic component: if $\mathbf{v}=e$ and $\alpha=2\pi i$, then $\alpha\cdot\mathbf{v} = e^{\pi i} = \cos(2\pi) + i\sin(2\pi) = 1=\mathbf{0}$, even though $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $\alpha\neq 0$. So the third example is **not** a vector space, and you messed up your verification somewhere. But since you don't tell us what you did, I don't know where exactly you messed up.

(It also goes wrong for finite fields, because the cardinality just doesn't work; a vector space of dimension $k$ over a field with $q$ elements has $q^k$ elements; but your underlying set here would have $(q-1)^k$ elements, which cannot be a power of $q$.)

The first example is fine, **provided** that you are viewing $C_p$ multiplicatively: if $C_p=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{p-1}\}$, and you look at $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as the field with $p$ elements, what you are *really* doing is looking at the standard $1$ dimensional vector space, except that, because instead of using addition for your vector operation you are using multiplication, then scalar multiplication becomes exponentiation: taking "logarithms base $x$" you obtain an isomorphism to $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a vector space over itself: if $\log_x(x^a) = a\bmod p$, we use $\oplus$ for the vector addition, and use $\odot$ for the scalar product you defined, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\log_x(x^a\oplus x^b) &= \log_x(x^ax^b) = \log_x(x^{a+b}) = a+b = \log_x(x^a)+\log_x(x^b)\\
\log_x(r\odot (x^a)) &= \log_x((x^a)^r) = \log_x(x^{ar}) = ar = r\cdot \log_x(x^a).
\end{align*}$$

---

What goes wrong in Example 2 is a bit subtle. Associativity doesn’t *really* work for the scalar multiplication.

Probably the best way to understand this is to *really* nail down the elements and vector addition; because otherwise, you run into issues with the scalar multiplication, e.g., is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot (-1)$ equal to $i$, or to $-i$? Is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1$ equal to $1$, or to $-1$? And once you nail it down, you’ll run into issues, precisely because this is not a continuous operation on $S^1$.

For instance: identify $S^1$ with the real numbers in $[0,2\pi)$ by writing $z=e^{i\theta}$ with $0\leq \theta\lt 2\pi$. Then vector addition is really:
$$e^{i\theta} \oplus e^{i\eta} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
e^{i(\theta+\eta)} &\text{if }\theta+\eta\lt 2\pi,\\
e^{i(\theta+\eta-2\pi)}&\text{if }\theta+\eta\geq 2\pi.
\end{array}\right.$$
and the scalar product it given by
$$r\odot e^{i\theta} = e^{i(r\theta - 2k\pi)}$$
where $k$ is an integer such that $0\leq r\theta - 2k\pi \lt 2\pi$.

Now, take $e^{i\pi}$ and consider multiplication by $2$ and then by $\frac{1}{2}$. We get
$$\frac{1}{2}\odot(2\odot e^{i\pi}) = \frac{1}{2}\odot (e^{0i}) = e^{0i}.$$
However, 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\right)\odot e^{i\pi} = 1\odot e^{i\pi} = e^{i\pi}.$$
So the scalar multiplication is not really associative on $S^1$ for this vector space structure.

Comment: My verification that exponentiation satisfies the 4 rules for scalar multiplication:

identity f(1,z)=z^1=z for all z

f(a,z^b)=(z^b)^a=z^ab=f(ab,z) so associative

f(a+b,z)=z^(a+b)=z^a* z^b=f(a,z)* f(b,z) so distributive over field

and f(a,z+w)=(z*w)^a=z^a** w^a so distributive over group

Comment: sorry about not using a typeset, I'm not sure how

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm wondering where in those 4 axioms it fails then?

Comment: I suppose since 0x=0 comes from distributivity in F it must be that?

Comment: @Oddlyasymmetric:  “Sorry about not using a typeset, I’m not sure how.” You’ve been on this site over 2 years. Isn’t it about time for you to *learn* “how”?

Comment: @Oddlyasymmetric: The problem in the third example is that it isn’t well defined. The problem in the second example is that if you **actuallly** nail down what your elements are and what your addition *really* is, then the scalar multiplication is not associative. I’ll expand.

Comment: To return to this, a year later into my degree, this could be defined on the log-spiral right? In that case, It would be isomorphic to the real line (you're just going up in a spiral rather than along a straight line).

Comment: @Oddlyasymmetric: If all you are doing is a transport of structure, then it doesn’t matter what the set “looks like”.

Comment: Indeed- (if there is a canonical isomorphism, which in this case there is). At the time I was new to linear algebra and was just trying to explore what you could do from the definitions. Thanks for your help back then!